# Two Way table in knime?

Tags: knime

I am new to KNIME and I have a question, I have column splitter node that is outputting one column and one row. This will naturally have one value in the cell. I want to feed this value into a column of a table in KNIME. How do I do this? 
I Don't see two way tables in KNIME.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, do you have a table just consisting on 1 cell and you want to put this value into another table? or you want to filter a column table using a value you have in a cell?

and if you can attach a workflow example, it'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Cross Joiner** node to append the constant column. (There is also the **Table Row to Variable** and **Constant Value Column** combination if the constant value is one of the primitive types (String, Double, Int).)

You may need the **RowID** node to replace/restore the row ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "table row to variable" node to create a variable out of that value
Next, you can add a "Constant Value Column" node and use the variable you created in the above step as the value